# Figma Prototyping: create connections from multiple objects to one frame simultaneously?

Tags: prototyping, figma

In Figma, is there a way to create many connections to one object simultaneously? Say, I have a bunch of buttons that should all lead to the same frame; I'd like to select them all and drag all connections at once, but that doesn't seem to exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes.

You can't use drag and drop for multiple elements, you need to select all the buttons and click on the options in the **Prototype** panel. Sorry for the short answer but it's a short question.

Comment: That worked, thanks! Kind of a non-obvious feature.

Comment: I didn't understand how this works. Could someone explain this to me? Thanks!!

Comment: @DanaVazquez https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039832014-Design-Prototype-and-view-Code-in-the-Properties-Panel#prototype